# TCL remove an element from a list

Tags: list, element, tcl

How te remove an element from TCL list say:

1. which has index = 4
2. which has value = "aa"

I have Googled and have not found any built-in function yet.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
set mylist {a b c}
puts $mylist
a b c
```

Remove by index

```
set mylist [lreplace $mylist 2 2]
puts $mylist 
a b
```

Remove by value

```
set idx [lsearch $mylist "b"]
set mylist [lreplace $mylist $idx $idx]
puts $mylist
a
```

Comment: This is great, but my list consists from sublists, and I want to check in each sublist if the value in the second index is 0 (for example), I want to remove that sublist. How I should do that. P.S. The problem is that [lindex $list] returns value not the reference

Comment: @Narek Then please update your question to be ask what you want, b/c drysdam answered what you asked.

Comment: Please change [lreplace $idx $idx] to [lreplace $mylist $idx $idx].

Comment: One tiny thing; Shouldn't the result in the last item be `a c`, rather than just `a`?

Answer (score 17):

The other way to remove an element is to filter it out. This Tcl 8.5 technique differs from the `lsearch`&`lreplace` method mentioned elsewhere in that it removes *all* of a given element from the list.

```
set stripped [lsearch -inline -all -not -exact $inputList $elemToRemove]
```

What it doesn't do is search through nested lists. That's a consequence of Tcl not putting effort into understanding your data structures too deeply. (You can tell it to search by comparing specific elements of the sublists though, via the `-index` option.)

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you want to replace element "b":

```
% set L {a b c d}
a b c d
```

You replace the first element 1 and last element 1 by nothing:

```
% lreplace $L 1 1
a c d
```

Answer (score 2):

`regsub` may also be suitable to remove a value from a list.

```
set mylist {a b c}
puts $mylist
  a b c

regsub b $mylist "" mylist

puts $mylist
  a  c
llength $mylist
  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapped up what others have done

```
proc _lremove {listName val {byval false}} {
    upvar $listName list

    if {$byval} {
        set list [lsearch -all -inline -not $list $val]
    } else {
        set list [lreplace $list $val $val]
    }

    return $list
}
```

Then call with

```
Inline edit, list lappend
    set output [list 1 2 3 20]
    _lremove output 0
    echo $output
    >> 2 3 20

Set output like lreplace/lsearch
    set output [list 1 2 3 20]
    echo [_lremove output 0]
    >> 2 3 20

Remove by value
    set output [list 1 2 3 20]
    echo [_lremove output 3 true]
    >> 1 2 20

Remove by value with wildcar
    set output [list 1 2 3 20]
    echo [_lremove output "2*" true]
    >> 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this :

```
set i 0
set myl [list a b c d e f]

foreach el $myl {
   if {$el in {a b e f}} {
      set myl [lreplace $myl $i $i]
   } else {
      incr i
   }
}
set myl
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways.

```
# index
set mylist "a c b"
set mylist [lreplace $mylist 2 2]
puts $mylist 
a b
    
# value
set idx [lsearch $mylist "b"]
set mylist [lreplace $mylist $idx $idx]
puts $mylist
a
```