# How to remove the first item in a list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

What I want to do is only remove the first item in the list. I checked out the documentation and it seems that lremove is the command that is used to remove items from a list.

Here what I tried:

```
set list {1 2 3 4 5}
lremove $list 0
puts $list
```

I would like the above code to print out: 2,3,4,5. But instead it says lremove is invalid command name.

Comment: You must have been looking at documentation for a different version of Tcl than the one you're using. The `lremove` command was added in Tcl 8.7, which is still in alpha.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701947/tcl-remove-an-element-from-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl doesn't have an `lremove` command. But it has several alternatives:

```
set list [lrange $list 1 end]
```

```
set list [lreplace $list 0 0]
```

```
set list [lassign $list dummy]
```

And, in 8.7:

```
set list [lremove $list 0]
```

```
lpop list 0
```

None of these will work with your input data as presented; Tcl uses whitespace to separate list elements, not commas. We need to do some prep and post work too:

```
set list [split "1,2,3,4,5" ","]
set list [lreplace $list 0 0]
puts [join $list ","]
```

Comment: The `lremove` command was added in Tcl 8.7 (via tip 367). Author: you!

Comment: Note that `lrange`, `lreplace`, `lassign` and `lremove` take the _list as a value_ and return the new list, and `lpop` takes a _list in a variable_ and modifies it in place.